# Wallet open failed

Tags: oracle, wallet

I have a oracle server installed in a machine and e oracle client on another machine. I have created a wallet using this commands

`C:\Users\MRBULL93>mkstore -wrl C:\VideoWallet -create`

`C:\Users\MRBULL93>mkstore -wrl C:\VideoWallet -createCredential kejvidoko SYSTEM`

also changed the sqlnet.ora file as follows

```
 # sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: 
 C:\app\MRBULL93\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
 # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

 # This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
 # install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
 # authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

 SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

 NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)



 WALLET_LOCATION =
 (SOURCE =
     (METHOD=FILE)
     (METHOD_DATA =
     (DIRECTORY =C:\VideoWallet)
    )
    )

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

========================================================

I can modify the password using cmd and I can also open it with Wallet manager but when I call it

`SQLPLUS /@kejvidoko` I get the following message

> ERROR: ORA-12578: TNS:wallet open failed

Can someone tell me how can i fix this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some versions of Oracle, you *cannot* put space between the beginning-of-line and the WALLET_LOCATION keyword, and you *must* put space between the beginning-of-line and the definition of a wallet. Your snippet indicates that you failed at one of these things. I think they removed this silly requirement starting from some Oracle version, but better safe than sorry.

Good:

```
#<- line begins here
WALLET_LOCATION=
      (SOURCE=...
      blabla
      )
```

Possibly wrong:

```
#<- line begins here
 WALLET_LOCATION=
      (SOURCE=...
      blabla
      )
```

Possibly wrong:

```
#<- line begins here
WALLET_LOCATION=
(SOURCE=...
blabla
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never too late :

You cannot use wallet with SYSTEM user.
Wallet is for user (at OS level) for connecting against DB thought sys (as oracle user do).
Create user at OS level (named myuser/myuser  for i.e.) and issue

mkstore -wrl C:\VideoWallet -createCredential kejvidoko myuser
       enter credential

and voila.
When trying connecting, don't forget the 'as sysdba' argument.
http://mohamedazar.com/2012/03/25/how-to-configure-clients-to-use-external-password-stores/